fix Prototype_Pollution error from checkmarx
the word 'substring(1)' in line window.location.search.substring(1) get error Prototype_Pollution,
Assigning external properties without validation may allow object properties pollution and affect application's normal behavior.
how fix this code?
var QueryString = function () {
// This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
// the return value is assigned to QueryString!
var query_string = {};

const allowed = new Set([
    'rqid',
    'rowId',
    'sid',
    'RequestId',
    'RequestTypeID',
    'mode',
    'id',
    'requestIdList',
]);

var query = DOMPurify.sanitize(window.location.search.substring(1));
var vars = query.split("&");

for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");

    // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
        if (allowed.has(pair[0])) {
            query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
        // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
        if (allowed.has(pair[0])) {
            var arr = [query_string[pair[0]], decodeURIComponent(pair[1])];
            query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
        }
        // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
        if (allowed.has(pair[0])) {
            query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));

        }
    }
}

return query_string;

}();


i succsess,
i change my code to:
var QueryString = function () {
// This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
// the return value is assigned to QueryString!
var query_string_help = {};
var query_string = new Map();

const allowed = new Set([
    'rqid',
    'rowId',
    'sid',
    'RequestId',
    'RequestTypeID',
    'mode',
    'id',
    'requestIdList',
]);

var query = DOMPurify.sanitize(window.location.search.substring(1));
var vars = query.split("&");

for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");


    var key = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
    var value = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');

    // If first entry with this name
    if (!query_string.has(key)) {
        if (allowed.has(key)) {
            query_string.set(key, value);
        }
    } else {
        // If second or later entry with this name
        if (allowed.has(key)) {
            var existingValue = query_string.get(key);
            if (Array.isArray(existingValue)) {
                existingValue.push(value);
                query_string.set(key, existingValue);
            } else {
                query_string.set(key, [existingValue, value]);
            }
        }
    }

}

query_string_help = Object.fromEntries(query_string)

return query_string_help;
}();

